# how to get database data in jtable

Tags: java, database

I have a jtable in my netbeans desktop application which I want to populate from a database.

I would like to know the binding code along with how to refresh the table after inserting/deleting some entry.

I have a button that shows the frame included jtable the actioncommand is below

```
 try{ 
     Class.forName("Mydrivername").newInstance();
     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionurl,id,password); 
     PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement) con.preparedStatement("select * from datavasetablename");
     ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()){
         row[0]= rs.getInt("Id"); 
         row[1]= rs.getString("name"); 
         mytablemodel.addRow(row);
         frame.show();
   }
 } catch(Exception e){

 }
```

When I first show the frame everything is fine but when I hide the frame and show it again everything is gone completely.

Comment: Any database? That's quite difficult to answer.

Comment: Did you retrieve data from the database already? You just want to display it, @Akanksha Dixit ?

Comment: I've a btn that show the frame included jtable the actioncommand is below -try{ Class.forName("Mydrivername").newInstance(); Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionurl,id,password); PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement) con.preparedStatement("select * from datavasetablename"); ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery(); while(rs.next()){ row[0]= rs.getInt("Id"); row[1]= rs.getString("name"); mytablemodel.addRow(row); frame.show();}} catch(Exception e){}  when I first show frame everything is fine but when I hide frame and rshow it again everything has gone completel

Comment: @Akanksha Dixit Notice that I updated your question based on your comments (edit is pending peer review). Please try to provide as more information in your question as possible. 

For what I can see, your `row` object seems to be inserted on the `mytablemodel`several times. Maybe it should be reinstantiated?

Comment: What should I do to overcome this problem?  Can't make a solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, the code where you instantiate the `row` object should be **also** placed inside the `while(rs.next()){` statement and then it should work.

If you use the same instance then all the items in the list will have the same properties. E.g.:

```
try{ 
     Class.forName("Mydrivername").newInstance();
     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionurl,id,password); 
     PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement) con.preparedStatement("select *    from datavasetablename");
     ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next())
     {
         row = new YourRowType();// Change this line to the correct type of    the row object
         row[0]= rs.getInt("Id"); 
         row[1]= rs.getString("name"); 
         mytablemodel.addRow(row);
         frame.show();
     }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {

  }
```

Comment: Thankx for your guidance. Successfully created a method that filles all my jtable from different database tables.  Thankx again

Answer (score 0):

in every insert-delete i reload all with

```
public Object[][] getDatos() {
    int registros = 0;
    //We first perform the COUNT to know the size of the matrix
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstm = con.getConnection().prepareStatement(""
                + "SELECT count(idDocente) as total FROM docente;");
        ResultSet res = pstm.executeQuery();
        res.next();//registros es igual al numero de materiales en la BD
        registros = res.getInt("total");
        res.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    //declaramos el tamaño de la matriz[numero de materiales][cantidad de atributos]
    Object[][] fila = new String[registros][6];

    try {
        PreparedStatement pstm = con.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT "
                + " codigo,nombre,apaterno,amaterno,telefono,correoElectronico "
                + " FROM docente"
                + " ORDER BY idDocente;");
        ResultSet res = pstm.executeQuery();
        int i = 0;
        while (res.next()) {
            String estCodigo = res.getString("codigo");
            String estNombre = res.getString("nombre");
            String estCantidad = res.getString("apaterno");
            String estDescripcion = res.getString("amaterno");
            String estFecha = res.getString("telefono");
            String estISBN = res.getString("correoElectronico");

            fila[i][0] = estCodigo;
            fila[i][1] = estNombre;
            fila[i][2] = estCantidad;
            fila[i][3] = estDescripcion;
            fila[i][4] = estFecha;
            fila[i][5] = estISBN;
            i++;
        }
        res.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fila;
}
```

View:

```
private void updateTabla() {
    String[] columNames = {"Code:", "Name:", "Surname:", "Surname", "Cell phone:", "E-mail:"};
    dtMaterial = objCtrl.getDatos();
    DefaultTableModel datos = new DefaultTableModel(dtMaterial, columNames);
    tblMaterial.setModel(datos);
}
```

Comment: Thankx going to try this. But beside the code i_Couldn't understand anything. If u can please make this in simple english

Comment: Hey @Daniel Mera Alvarez! Maybe you should post the code that is essential to answer the question, writing it in English, at least in the comments. Thanks for your support =)